# where files are created in docker run? local machine or docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

this is my first question in stackoverflow :))
When i start my rails app with docker following the link https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project.

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs    <- this install dependencies into docker container
RUN mkdir /myapp   <- this create myapp folder into docker container
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp       <- my confused there
```

If the command "RUN bundle install" is same as "RUN mkdir /myapp", so my project skeleton files will be created within docker container instead of local machine. But why need the last command "ADD . /myapp"? Because that command add the current folder in local machine to /myapp folder in docker container.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ADD` command copy the content of your current host directory (only new files) inside `/myapp` directory of your container.

1. `RUN mkdir /myapp`: Create an empty `/myapp` directory inside the container.
2. `WORKDIR /myapp`: Set `/myapp` as your work directory inside the container.
3. `ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile` and `ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock`
   : Add your host `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to `/myapp/`.
4. `RUN bundle install`: Install dependencies of your `Gemfile`
5. `ADD . /myapp`: Add your application code to `/myapp` directory (only new files).

Check Dockerfile reference for `ADD` command if you need further information about this command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Hope this helps, good luck and welcome to SO!

Comment: thank you for your answer. But you donot focus on my confused: if my app skeleton files are created in docker container after "RUN bundle install", then why need to add them again into container by "ADD . /myapp"?

Comment: If you don't have any new file in your current directory, and all files are created after `RUN bundle install`, simply, the ADD command will do nothing. You can remove it.

Comment: Please, validate the answer of if it was helpful for you :)